# Disable fancyBox 2 from closing when clicking the background

Tags: jquery, fancybox

In fancyBox 2, is there a key/value I could set that will disable the lightbox from closing when the user clicks the background (semi-transparent black background)?

I only want to give them the option to click the actual (X) close button in the top right hand corner.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For version 2.x use

```
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    closeClick  : false, // prevents closing when clicking INSIDE fancybox
    helpers     : { 
        overlay : {closeClick: false} // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox
    }
 });
```

if `closeClick` is set to `true` (default) fancybox will close if clicking over the content so with these two combined options the only possible way to close fancybox is with the `close` (X) button

Comment: why isn't this answer marked as right and accepted? it is the right one and it works and you got 6 upvotes

Comment: this SHOULD be the accepted answer.  the first `closeClick  : false` is the default so it's not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

This will disable closing fancybox when clicking on the overlay (the semi-transparent background)

```
    fancyEls.fancybox({
        helpers : { 
            overlay : {
                closeClick: false
            } // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox
        }
    });
```

This will disable all default click methods of closing fancybox

```
    fancyEls.fancybox({
        closeBtn : false,
        closeClick : false,
        helpers : { 
            overlay : {
                closeClick: false
            } // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox
        },
        keys : {
            close: null
        } // prevents close when clicking escape button
    });
```

And this will do the same as well as disabling slideshow functionality

```
    fancyEls.fancybox({
        modal : true //If set to true, will disable navigation and closing  
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Fancybox site API](http://www.fancybox.net/api) you could/should use

```
$.fancybox({
   ...
   'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
     let **adduser** be my target selector

```
$('.adduser').fancybox({
'hideOnOverlayClick': false
});
```

Comment: that option is for fancybox v1.3.x. Options in fancybox v2.x are new and not compatible with previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent close button- use:

```
defaults: {  closeBtn   : false,}
```

To prevent overlay close - use :

```
F.helpers.overlay = {
        defaults : {closeClick : false,      // if true, fancyBox will be closed when user clicks on the overlay }}
```

To prevent escape click close :

```
defaults: {keys  : {//close  : [27], // escape key
                close  : null, } }
```