# FullCalendar + FancyBox2: Passing and setting input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fancybox-2, cakephp-2.3

I'd need some help. I'm trying to build up FullCalendar and FancyBox2 combination. I have a function like this, when user clicks a day:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                var url = '/reservations/add';
                var data = url;
                var dayClickDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy');

                $.fancybox({
                    'hideOnContentClick': false, //option for v1.3.4 (outdated)
                    'type': 'iframe',
                    'href': data,
                    'width': 500,
                    'height': 100,
                    'transitionIn': 'none', //option for v1.3.4 (outdated)
                    'transitionOut': 'none', //option for v1.3.4 (outdated)

                    afterLoad: function() {
                        $("#resStartDate").val(dayClickDate);
                    },
                    afterClose: function() {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    }
                });
            },
```

FancyBox opens a page in iframe, where user can make a new reservation. It should set the clicked day's date to an input value. The code above does not work.

Does someone have idea how I could get this working? Thank you.

Comment: If you are using fancybox 2, some of you API options are outdated (see my notes in your post). Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs for the right options of the version you are using.

Comment: hints : `transitionIn` was replaced by `openEffect`. For `hideOnContentClick` check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9732878/1055987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on where the selectors `#resStartDate` and `#calendar` are : in the *parent* page or in the opened page inside the `iframe` ?

If they are inside the opened page (which I assume they are), then you should find them first inside the `iframe` before passing any value so try

```
afterLoad: function() {
   $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find("#resStartDate").val(dayClickDate);
},
afterClose: function() {
   $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
}
```

**NOTE**: working with iframes? always consider the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: I am thinking that maybe `fullCalendar` should be also installed in the page inside the `iframe`