# Fancybox popup close button not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

any idea why the close button is not appearing in my newsletter popup box?

Many thanks

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.fancybox('#newsletterpopup', {
            modal: true, // this prevents fancybox to close unless close unless ".non-merci" is clicked
            showCloseButton: true,
            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                    css: {
                        'background': 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.3)'
                    }
                }
            },
            afterShow: function () {
                // enables a way to close fancybox
                $(".non-merci").on("click", function () {
                    $.fancybox.close()
                });
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false;
    } else {
        openFancybox();
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', {
        expires: 0.0001
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set

```
modal: true
```

close button will **NEVER** show up, regardless `closeBtn` is set to `true`.

You either remove the `modal` option (which default is `false`) or set it to `false`

**Notice** that `showCloseButton` is an option for fancybox v1.3.x.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue is that if I don't set the box as modal, I'm not able to input anything in the newsletter email field (as per your suggestion in this post http://goo.gl/oxrUdP ). Is there an alternative to that? (close button AND able to update the field). Many thanks

Comment: @Greg make sure `closeClick` is set to `false`. Learn more http://stackoverflow.com/a/9732878/1055987

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use:**

`closeBtn:'<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a>'` instead of `showCloseButton`.

And try to use jQuery version 1.8 or lower instead of 1.10

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what tools you are using. I use gulp and I noticed that the file (fancybox_sprite.png) is there, but the path can be wrong, especially if you are using gulp to compile for you. Sometimes they can get misplaced. Either host the image in the cloud or correct the path to the file.

Hope this helps. Also if you want to confirm that you actually have the correct config, you can use inspector to check if there's `.fancybox-close` class. If it's there, then this means your path is not pointing to the png file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the latest modal example from [Fancybox](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) you can add the the close button to the DOM along with `modal: true`.

```js
$('#newsletterpopup').fancybox({
    modal: true,
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.3)'
            }
        }
    },
});
```

```css
#trueModal{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<a data-fancybox="" data-src="#trueModal" data-modal="true" href="javascript:;">Open modal</a>

<div id="trueModal">
  <div>Your content</div>
  <button data-fancybox-close>Close modal</button>
</div>
```